# Ways to avoid headaches while cooking

Tags: food, comfort

I have recently started to learn how to cook. Whenever I am trying to make a chapati or to cook a vegetable, I start experiencing an acute headache, most likely because of the steam or maybe the flame in burner gas stove, though I am not sure and that's the very reason I have posted it here. Also, if this is the case, what can I do to avoid such headaches. I don't have any kind of other medical issues apart from having dust allergy.

Comment: This is touching towards medical advice/hacks, which we don't do. But you might get better responses/aid if you go to either http://cooking.stackexchange.com/ which is closer related to cooking (or possibly http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/ related to gas issues)

Comment: Yes, "headaches while cooking" is not an normal, everyday occurrence. It would be very irresponsible to start hacking up a solution where an unexplored medical or health issue may be involved.

Comment: Yes, I understand that now. I have posted this question on other site.

Comment: is there an option for a personal chat here?

Answer (score 3):

Try running the stove for a few minutes without a pan on the burner. If you still get a headache: you may be experiencing [carbon monoxide poisoning](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Carbon-monoxide-poisoning/Pages/Symptoms.aspx). In this case, you need to massively increase the ventilation in your kitchen.

Comment: it might be off-topic but could only the water vapour cause headache?

Comment: I'm not a medical professional, but that seems unlikely. Do you get headaches when you walk in the rain?

Answer (score 0):

If the steam is causing problems get a fan and increase the ventilation.
If the gas stove is causing the problem check for Carbon Monoxide.

Either way, I would recommend getting some ventilation.